# Как реализовать автоматическое выпадающее меню?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dropdown

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, реализацию, при которой бы при уменьшении экрана ссылки, которые не помещаются в одну строку, автоматически складывались бы в выпадающее меню. Благодарю за помощь!

```css
.header-item {
 padding: 7px 0;
}
.hi {
 display: inline-block;
}
.hi:after {
 content: '|';
 margin: 0 17px 0;
 display: inline-block;
 color: #ccc;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-item">
<div class="hi"><a href="#">Первый пункт</a></div>
<div class="hi"><a href="#">Второй пункт</a></div>
<div class="hi"><a href="#">Третий пункт</a></div>
<div class="hi"><a href="#">Четвертый пункт</a></div>
<div class="hi"><a href="#">Пятый пункт</a></div>
<div class="hi"><a href="#">Шестой пункт</a></div>
<div class="hi"><a href="#">Седьмой пункт</a></div>
<div class="hi"><a href="#">Восьмой пункт</a></div>
</div>
```

Уточняю вопрос: при уменьшении экрана необходимо, чтобы не все сразу ссылки помещались в выпадающее меню, а поочередно, по мере их выхода за пределы видимости экрана. спасибо!

Comment: Здравствуйте **LADYX**! Не очень понятна задача, как только начинается перенос одного пункта  меню на новую строку, сразу все пункты меню должны "сложиться" или только тот что был перенесен? Есть требования к тому, как это необходимо реализовать? Поставил минус вам, как только дополните вопрос, с радостью уберу минус.

Comment: Не уверен, что я буду доделывать, возможно у вас будет желание доделать [**ссылка**](http://codepen.io/alexandr-kazakov/pen/BWgErN?editors=0110)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420151/manipulate-jquery-menu-on-re-size-for-responsive-layout

Comment: @LADYX непонятно, устроил вас в итоге ответ(который вы приняли) или нет. У вас есть в меню логотип? Лучше выложите полностью всю верстку(html/css) блока/секции, т.к. даже рабочий вариант вам возможно будет сложно применить в своем случае.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Первым делом напишем необходимый CSS: добавим всем элементам `white-space: nowrap`, чтобы они не переносились на следующую строку; скроем меню по [правилам доступности](https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/05/html5-accessibility-chops-hidden-and-aria-hidden/) — это нам также потребуется в дальнейшем при расчетах ширины скрытых элементов.
2. При нажатии на кнопку будем отображать и скрывать меню с элементами, которые не поместились в список.
3. Функция `getInvisible()` возвращает нам массив элементов, которые не помещаются в ширину списка. Основа всех расчетов — метод `.getBoundingClientRect()`.
4. Функция `moveForward()` переносит все не помещающиеся элементы в выпадающее меню.
5. Функция `moveBackward()` переносит элементы из выпадающего меню обратно — это нам потребуется при ресайзе окна.
6. Функция [`debounce()`](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) нужна для оптимизации вызова функции при ресайзе.
7. Добавляем слушателя на событие ресайза и вызываем функцию `restart()`, которая вызывает `moveBackward()` и `moveForward()`. Таким образом, при ресайзе все элементы возвращаются обратно в строку, а затем те, которые не помещаются отправляются обратно в выпадающий список.

UPD. добавил также подсчет количества скрытых элементов и скрытие кнопки, когда все элементы меню видны.

```js
let button = document.getElementById('menu-toggler');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.menu').classList.toggle('menu--open');
});

window.addEventListener('resize', debounce(restart, 250));

moveForward();

function moveForward() {
  let listElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#list .li')),
      invisibleElements = getInvisible(listElements),
      menuList = document.getElementById('menu-list');

  invisibleElements.forEach(function(item) {
    menuList.appendChild(item);
  });
  
  if(!invisibleElements.length) { 
    button.setAttribute('hidden', true);
  } else {
    button.removeAttribute('hidden');
  }
  
  button.innerHTML = invisibleElements.length;
}

function moveBackward() {
  let menuListElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#menu-list .li')),
      list = document.getElementById('list');

  menuListElements.forEach(function(item) {
    list.appendChild(item);
  });
}

function restart() {
  moveBackward();
  moveForward();
}

function getInvisible(listElements) {
  let list = document.getElementById('list');

  let invisible = listElements.filter(function(item) {
    if (item.getBoundingClientRect().left + item.getBoundingClientRect().width > list.clientWidth) {
      return item;
    }
  });

  return invisible;
}

function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this,
      args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};
```

```css
#menu-toggler {
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  top: 8px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}

#list {
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#menu-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.menu {
  border: 1px solid;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  right: 8px;
  top: 50px;
}

.menu--open {
  clip: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li class="li">element #1</li>
  <li class="li">element #2</li>
  <li class="li">element #3</li>
  <li class="li">element #4</li>
  <li class="li">element #5</li>
  <li class="li">element #6</li>
  <li class="li">element #7</li>
  <li class="li">element #8</li>
  <li class="li">element #9</li>
  <li class="li">element #10</li>
  <li class="li">element #11</li>
  <li class="li">element #12</li>
  <li class="li">element #13</li>
  <li class="li">element #14</li>
  <li class="li">element #15</li>
  <li class="li">element #16</li>
  <li class="li">element #17</li>
  <li class="li">element #18</li>
  <li class="li">element #19</li>
  <li class="li">element #20</li>
</ul>

<button id="menu-toggler">…</button>

<menu class="menu">
  <ul id="menu-list"></ul>
</menu>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте! 1). При всех открытых элементах кнопка должна исчезать, и появляться при первом закрытом(мне кажется такое поведение логичным). 2). Присутствует странная задержка, когда разворачиваем страницу(даже при не самом быстром ресайзе) и пункты меню добавляются сразу пачкой.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov 1) это уже есть 2) это не баг, это фича — прочитайте внимательно описание, пункт 6.

Comment: @LADYX чтобы отобразить количество достаточно записать в `innerHTML` кнопки длину массива скрытых элементов, см. обновленную функцию `moveForward()`.

Comment: @Sasha Omelchenko Я конечно просмотрел, что кнопка исчезает, моя вина, правда редко встретишь меню подобное на 20 пунктов. Вы возможно более опытный в разработке чем я, и мне не стоит пока что с вами спорить, но отмечу еще раз, что задержка в появлении меню выглядит совсем не здорово.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov да всё норм :-) что касается задержки, то тут смотрите какая ситуация: можно сделать без оной, но особенность события resize такова, что оно вызывается *постоянно* при изменении размеров окна. а значит все пересчеты и изменения в DOM будут происходить тоже постоянно — это сильно нагружает браузер. вместе с функцией debounce пересчет выполнится *один* раз через 250 мс после завершения ресайза.

Comment: для пользователя задержка в формировании такого меню не так страшна, как вероятное подвисание всей страницы (или даже браузера, если функция еще более серьезная).

Comment: @LADYX Можно, например, выставьте любую процентную ширину. Ну и calc() очень хорошо поддерживается, кстати, разве что браузеры трех-четырехлетней давности с ним не дружат.

Answer (score 3):

```css
#demo {
        margin: 30px 0 50px 0;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
 
#demo .wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 180px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
 
#demo .parent {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #F9F9F9;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
  color: #282D31;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: border-radius .1s linear, background .1s linear, z-index 0s linear;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .8s;
  text-align: center;
}
#demo .parent:hover,с#demo .content:hover ~ .parent {
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0s;
}
 
#demo .content:hover ~ .parent {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 
#demo .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 0;
  width: 180px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: height .5s ease;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .4s;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
 
#demo .wrapper:active .content {
  height: 123px;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
}
 
#demo .content:hover {
  height: 123px;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
}
 
 
#demo .content ul {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
 
#demo .content ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
 
#demo .content li:hover {
  background: #eee;
  color: #333;
}
 
#demo .content li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  color: #888;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
 
#demo .content li:last-of-type {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
   <ul>
    <a href="#"><li>Меню1</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Меню2</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Меню3</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Меню4</li></a>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">Выпадающее меню 1</div>
 </div>
 

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Автор [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15499972/4500765) предлагает следующий скрипт:

```
$().ready(function () { 

    //Обновляем меню в событии window.resize
    $(window).on("resize", function (e) {                                                   
        var parentWidth = $("#nav-bar-filter").parent().width() - 40;
        var ulWidth = $("#more-nav").outerWidth();                  
        var menuLi = $("#nav-bar-filter > li");                 
        var liForMoving = new Array(); 

        //Определим элементы, которые не влезают в меню
        menuLi.each(function () {                       
            ulWidth += $(this).outerWidth(); 
            if (ulWidth > parentWidth) {
                liForMoving.push($(this));
            }
        });                         
        if (liForMoving.length > 0) {   //Если есть элементы, которые не влезают -> перемещаем их в подменю
            e.preventDefault();                     
            liForMoving.forEach(function (item) {
                item.clone().appendTo(".subfilter");
                item.remove();
            });                         
        }
        else if (ulWidth < parentWidth) { //Проверяем, не нужно ли сдвинуть какие-то элементы обратно
            liForMoving = new Array();
            var moved = $(".subfilter > li");
            for (var i = moved.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 
                var tmpLi = $(moved[i]).clone();
                tmpLi.appendTo($("#nav-bar-filter"));
                ulWidth += $(moved[i]).outerWidth();
                if (ulWidth < parentWidth) {                                
                    $(moved[i]).remove();
                }
                else {
                    ulWidth -= $(moved[i]).outerWidth();
                    tmpLi.remove();
                }                           
            }                       
        }                       
        if ($(".subfilter > li").length > 0) { //Если есть скрытые элементы, показываем блок еще
            $("#more-nav").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#more-nav").hide();
        }
    });

    $(window).trigger("resize"); //Запустим скрипт при старте
});
```

Демо: http://jsfiddle.net/3AU2N/16/

Перевод ответа https://stackoverflow.com/a/15499972/4500765